# Copying text into a swf from mouse click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, flash

I have a swf file on my html page, and it has inputs on it. I'm just wondering if there is a certain way that I can use javascript or jquery, where I can click on a certain link or button that is coded onto the html page, where it'll insert text into the input field in the swf file.
[image]
Example

Comment: Did you even try anything? Before generating an SWF, you have to edit your Flash app's code to expect to receive that information from a JavaScript function. Compile to SWF then use it on your HTML page. If this is a random found-on-the-net SWF then it won't be possible.

Comment: I didnt downvote but I suspect its because this is a **programming** question but no problem code to fix is shown. Just a picture and something about a mystery SWF. You have a correct Answer below. Use External Interface to pass text from Javascript into Flash SWF. So also make sure you programmed the SWF to extract text via JS function when your button is pressed

Answer (score 1):

There are `ExternalInterface.call()` and `ExternalInterface.addCallback()` functions that can be used for communication between your container and SWF element. 
Please refer
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html#addCallback()

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

To use JavaScript or Jquery you must assign a univoque ID to the SVG.